# Nominate an old, locked, question for disappearance

Tags: discussion, specific-question, vote-to-delete

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349378/new-programming-jargon-you-coined

I find this one really grating. Why? Because it specifically invites egotistical bloviation: 'What have **you** coined?' If it was 'contribute interesting or useful jargon you have met' it wouldn't bother me so much as a retained fossil.

Comment: The amount of tears from people wanting it open for the badges they netted off that will be more than the finale of M*A*S*H

Comment: Isn't this what the "delete" feature is for?

Comment: It's been locked so that we can't vote to get rid of it.

Comment: Would a title edit be sufficient?  We could just make it a jargon file.

Comment: We could migrate it to Programmers together with a change in the title. Personally I'd love to keep this question *somewhere* around.

Comment: @Bill: That was already tried, but the OP rolled it back (see edit history). Also in the edit history: a disgusting amount of bumping the question to the front page by the OP.

Comment: @Bobby - **NO** it's not the sort of question we want on Programmers. If it gets migrated it **will** get closed and deleted in short order.

Comment: @ChrisF there are much worse questions *open* on Programmers.  "What have you coined" is terrible, but "Useful programming neologisms" is more what has been answered, anyway.

Comment: @Renesis - I know. I don't have the time to trawl through looking for them. I have to wait for flags and close votes.

Comment: @Bill a title edit couldn't hurt. However, it seems to me to be a classic incitement to bad questions.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to answer it, rather than stay in the safety of the comments section.

If the question title is the only problem, then edit the question!

If there's something else wrong with the question, then those who closed or locked it should state what's wrong with it.